# Configuring different PHP for different projects in httpd

Tags: php, apache

We have a GNU/Linux(with httpd) that is being used by different projects. Is it possible to use a different version of PHP only for a specific project?

Comment: I'd be interested to see this also. I have found the following which allows you to specify the PHP version based on a virtual host: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-version-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily

Comment: Assuming you use `php-fpm` instead of shitty `mod_php`, it's possible to run several different php versions, and have each virtual host use a different one. [Here's an article](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-multiple-php-versions-php-fpm-and-fastcgi-with-ispconfig-3-ubuntu-12.10) about that.